# Am I able to fix the headers in my DataFrame while still using Pandas html_read?

Tags: html, python-3.x, pandas

I want to pull an HTML table into a Pandas dataframe, and html_read so far has been the easiest method. However, some of the headers are coming through a little funky, and I'm trying to avoid fixing them manually in Excel.

I also tried several BeautifulSoup tutorials, but was unable to pull the tables into a dataframe rather than lists.

```
import pandas as pd
url = "https://www.espn.com/nba/stats/player/_/season/2017/seasontype/2/table/offensive/sort/avgAssists/dir/desc"
df = pd.read_html(url)[0]
df.to_excel("espn_table.xlsx")
```

I was hoping to get a simple copy of the table showing NBA assist leaders, but three things are happening: 
1. A full player/team list is populating a single cell (B4) in Excel 
2. A full player name list is appearing in rows 5-51, separate from the stats  they're associated with 
3. A second cell in Excel (B56) is displaying a duplicated copy of the table stats

Thanks in advance for any tips.

Comment: The reason is, that the table is constructed of nested tables. Pandas cannot handle this. If you look at the html, you will find `<table>` tags inside other `<table>` tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help.

As @jottbe pointed out, one should try to avoid reading the url twice.

```
dfs = pd.read_html(url)

df1 = dfs[1]
df2 = dfs[3]

df = df1.join(df2)
```

```
    Name    POS GP  MIN PTS FGM FGA FG% 3PM 3PA 3P% FTM FTA FT% REB AST STL BLK TO  DD2 TD3 PER
0   James HardenHOU PG  81  36.4    29.1    8.3 18.9    44.0    3.2 9.3 34.7    9.2 10.9    84.7    8.1 11.2    1.5 0.5 5.7 64  22  27.43
1   John WallWSH    PG  78  36.4    23.1    8.3 18.4    45.1    1.1 3.5 32.7    5.4 6.8 80.1    4.2 10.7    2.0 0.6 4.1 50  0   23.28
2   Russell WestbrookOKC    PG  81  34.6    31.6    10.2    24.0    42.5    2.5 7.2 34.3    8.8 10.4    84.5    10.7    10.4    1.6 0.4 5.4 62  42  30.7
3   Chris PaulLAC   PG  61  31.5    18.1    6.1 12.9    47.6    2.0 5.0 41.1    3.8 4.3 89.2    5.0 9.2 2.0 0.1 2.4 24  1   26.25
4   Ricky RubioMIN  PG  75  32.9    11.1    3.5 8.7 40.2    0.8 2.6 30.6    3.4 3.8 89.1    4.1 9.1 1.7 0.1 2.6 25  1   16.87
```

---

Now, `Name` column also contains two- or three-character abbreviations, which you could just get rid of using `.str.replace()`.

```
df['Name'] = df['Name'].str.replace(r'([A-Z]{2,3}$)', '')
```

```
    Name    POS GP  MIN PTS FGM FGA FG% 3PM 3PA 3P% FTM FTA FT% REB AST STL BLK TO  DD2 TD3 PER
0   James Harden    PG  81  36.4    29.1    8.3 18.9    44.0    3.2 9.3 34.7    9.2 10.9    84.7    8.1 11.2    1.5 0.5 5.7 64  22  27.43
1   John Wall   PG  78  36.4    23.1    8.3 18.4    45.1    1.1 3.5 32.7    5.4 6.8 80.1    4.2 10.7    2.0 0.6 4.1 50  0   23.28
2   Russell Westbrook   PG  81  34.6    31.6    10.2    24.0    42.5    2.5 7.2 34.3    8.8 10.4    84.5    10.7    10.4    1.6 0.4 5.4 62  42  30.7
3   Chris Paul  PG  61  31.5    18.1    6.1 12.9    47.6    2.0 5.0 41.1    3.8 4.3 89.2    5.0 9.2 2.0 0.1 2.4 24  1   26.25
4   Ricky Rubio PG  75  32.9    11.1    3.5 8.7 40.2    0.8 2.6 30.6    3.4 3.8 89.1    4.1 9.1 1.7 0.1 2.6 25  1   16.87
```

---

Lastly, you could easily save it as an excel table `df.to_excel("espn_table.xlsx")`

Comment: @sobrio35, I edited my initial answer showing how to clean the `df['Name'] column. Hope that helped!

Comment: Just one small thing, you should try to avoid reading the url twice. I mean `dfs=pd.read_html(url)` then `df1=dfs[1]` and `df1=dfs[3]`

Comment: @politicalscientist Thanks! I'm working through your `str.replace` line, wondering if you could point me to documentation on what you did there?

Comment: @sobrio35, Here's the documentation for [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html), it works the same as [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) btw. The first argument you provide is the pattern (of [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)), and the second one is a character or a combination of characters you want to replace a defined pattern with. I suggest using this site: https://regex101.com/ for practising.